# Uniform Random Variable: Correlation and Independence

Tags: probability, random-variables, uniform-distribution, correlation, covariance

Let X be a uniform random variable defined on the interval $(0,1)$. If $Y = 6X^2−6X+1$, compute the correlation of X and Y . Are X and Y independent? Are X and Y uncorrelated?

So my work is.

$F(X) = \int{1} dx = x$

$E(X) = \frac{a+b}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$

$F(Y) = \int 6X^2-6X+1 dx = 2x^3-3x^2+x$

So is $E(XY) = \int\int f(x)f(y)dxdy$?

Comment: $\mathsf P(X=x)=0$ because $X$ is a *continuous random variable*.$\;$  You need the CDF, $F_X(x)= \mathsf P(X\leq x) = x$, or the pdf $f_X(x)=1$

Comment: As I thought. The CDF rather than the PMF. Assuming I correct everything. Would my way of solving for E(XY) correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$X$ is a **uniform continuous random variable** on the support $(0;1)$.

*Some* features of this are that it has a cummulative distribution function $F_X(x) = x\;\raise{0.25ex}\chi_{x\in(0;1)}$, a probability mass function of $f_X(x)=1\,\raise{0.25ex}\chi_{x\in(0;1)}$, an expectation $\mathsf E(X)= \frac 1 2$ and variance: $\mathsf E(X^2)-\mathsf E(X)^2 = \frac 1 {12}$

Indeed $\mathsf E(X^k) = \int_0^1 x^k\,f_X(x)\operatorname d x = \frac{1}{k+1}$ for all $\Re (k)>-1$

Use this.

---

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf E(X^k) & =\frac{1}{k+1}
\\[2ex]
\mathsf E(XY) & = \mathsf E(6X^3-6X^2+X)
\\[1ex] & = 6\mathsf E(X^3)-6\mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(X)
\\[1ex]
& =
\\[2ex]
\mathsf {Cov}(X,Y) & = \mathsf E(XY)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(Y)
\\[1ex]
& = \mathsf E(6X^3-6X^2+X)-\mathsf E(X)\mathsf E(6X^2-6X+1)
\\[1ex]
& = 6\mathsf E(X^3)-6\mathsf E(X^2)+\mathsf E(X)-\mathsf E(X)\Big(6\mathsf E(X^2)-6\mathsf E(X)+\mathsf E(1)\Big)
\\[1ex] 
& =
\end{align}$$

Comment: I updated the post can you look at it?

Comment: No, @FutureUIUXDeveloper ,  just use linearity of expectation, and that $\mathsf E(X^k)=\frac{1}{k+1}$ .

Comment: Your method worked. However there was a typo. There is suppose to be a 6 infront of the $X^3$ in $E(XY)$ and similarly in $E(Y)$. Turns out X and Y are Independent however they aren't correlated. It makes sense now. I appreciate the help again. I learned how to approach the problem now. Thank you a ton.

Comment: Which the typo I assume you put in there for fun :)

Answer (score 2):

That's too much work, you would rather do
$$E[XY] = E[X(6X^2-6X+1)].$$
Then use the properties of expectation.

---

For the covariance, I would proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
\text{Cov}(X,Y) &= \text{Cov}(X,6X^2-6X+1)\\
&=6\text{Cov}(X,X^2)-6\text{Cov}(X,X)+\text{Cov}(X,1)\\
&=6\left[E[X^3]-E[X]E[X^2]\right]-6\text{Var}(X)+0\\
&=6\left[\int_0^1x\cdot x^3\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{4}\right)\right]-\frac{1}{2}\\
&=6\left[\frac{1}{5}\cdot 1 -\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{4}{12}\right] -\frac{1}{2}\\
&=-\frac{3}{10}.
\end{align*}

Comment: would this simply be: $[(0)*6((0)^3-6(0)^2+(0)]+[6(1)^3-6(1)^2+(1)]= 1$ @probablyme

Comment: I just showed how to get the covariance. It is possible I made a little arithmetic mistake. You should try to do the rest.

Comment: Okay I will give it a look.  I was attempting a weird way to solve the problem. I know where to go from here. Thanks